# How to make border exactly with button using css

Tags: html, css

My objective is align border perfectly to the icons (the line of the border should start with delete icon and end with archived icon without containing any up and space in between the border)

I've tried in this way:

```
 <div style={{ border: "1px solid black" }}>
      <DeleteIcon />
      <span>Hello</span>
      <ArchiveIcon />
    </div>
```

But still i could see some small space on the top of the icon and bottom too **for border and icon**.  Can anyone help me this query?

Here is the working one: (https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-chandrasekhar-gpjuh)

Comment: You can try `display: flex;` for the container div and `align-items: center;`

Comment: @ozgur - Hi, it's not working for me

Comment: I forgot you are using React. So it should be alignItems as hussain stated in his answer.

Comment: @ozgur - Still facing issue in the right and left hand-side of the icons. the border is having a small in left and right

Answer (score 2):

[image]

There are many solutions but this should get the job done for you. Use flex box and specify height. Check the solution below.

```
<div style={{ border: "1px solid black", height: "1rem" , display:"flex", alignItems: "center"
```

Comment: Hi, this works for me but i want the same thing with left and right too. Could you please help me. Even the border should touch the left and right for the icons

Comment: add this in the style width:"fit-content"

Comment: still i'm facing the same issue. left and right having a space. It's not touching the icon.

Comment: I was able to achieve that but I recommend using it. Its hard coded. use this if you think it works.. Add styles to icons, 
<DeleteIcon style={{margin: "-7%"}}/>
<ArchiveIcon style={{margin: "19%"}}/>

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div style={{ border: "1px solid black", lineHeight: "24px" }}>
```

and

```
<style>
.MuiSvgIcon-root {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

should do the trick.

Currently, the icons are placed on the base line (the invisible line, where letters are aligned to). The two changes set (a) the height of the base line so that the text is centered between the icons and (b) the icons exactly in the middle of the resulting box.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div
  style={{
    border: "1px solid black",
    display: "flex",
    alignItems: "center",
    width: "fit-content"
  }}
>
```